# Как правильно составить SQL запрос

Tags: php, sql

Имеется данный запрос:

```
 $sql = "SELECT status FROM tickets WHERE partnerId=125362 AND status=\'success\'";
```

Я взял это запрос из phpmyadmin, т.е. он успешно выполнился, но когда я этот код использую в php скрипте то мне выдает ошибку:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'
```

Почему возникает подобная ошибка, с чем она связана? И второй вопрос - как мне правильно вставить переменную в запросе вместо цифр? `partnerId=125362`

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. к составлению SQL запросов данная ошибка отношения не имеет. Это проблема в неправильном написании РНР кода. Базовый синтаксис РНР следует выучить до начала работы с базами данных. В данном случае где-то перед переменной $sql не закрыта скобка.
2. Слеши в этом запрос не нужны.
3. Чтобы добавить любую переменную в запрос, ее надо передавать отдельно, чтобы БД сама подставила ее на место *плейсхолдера*.

Например для ПДО код будет такой

```
$sql = "SELECT status FROM tickets WHERE partnerId=? AND status='success'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([125362]);
$tickets = $stmt->fetchAll();
// в массиве tickets лежат все билеты
```

Comment: если он пдо использует))